# Exoplayer Integration with Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, exoplayer

I am trying to Integrate Exoplayer with Xamarin but somehow I am able to play small size video which are located at cdn servers but for large file exoplayer goes to the ideal state and does not play video.

I have also tried Exoplayer Dash for mpd file using streaming servers but still not able to play large size videos in xamarin. Please help me understand where I am lacking.

Comment: Until you share your code we would be just speculating

Comment: Refer to https://github.com/martijn00/ExoPlayerXamarin

Comment: sampleSource = new ExtractorSampleSource(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url), dataSource, allocator,BUFFER_SEGMENT_COUNT * BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);
 videoRenderer = new MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer(this, sampleSource, MediaCodecSelector.Default,1);
audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource, MediaCodecSelector.Default);
 exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.NewInstance(RENDERER_COUNT);
 exoPlayer.Prepare(videoRenderer, audioRenderer);
 exoPlayer.SendMessage(videoRenderer, MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer.MsgSetSurface,              surfaceView.Holder.Surface);exoPlayer.PlayWhenReady = true;

Comment: I am using the above code

Comment: Add this in the question, not as a comment! Edit the question @ShellyBhogal

Comment: I am able to play m3u8 file now but unable to play mp4 large size files